# Moving like methods into generic implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I am trying to refactor some code and have to admit that I am new to the concept of generics.

I have a base class:

BaseVarDef.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
public abstract class BaseVarDef<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    [Multiline]
    public string DeveloperDescription = "";

    public T Value;

    public void SetValue(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

}
```

Then I have several classes that derive from this. But they all contain the same 3 methods that I would like to refactor into this generic base class. The only difference is they expect either the generic type or class that is currently defining them.

FloatVar.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New FloatVar", menuName = "Variables/FloatVar")]
public class FloatVar : BaseVarDef<float>
{
    public void SetValue(FloatVar value)
    {
        Value = value.Value;
    }
    public void ApplyChange(float amount)
    {
        Value += amount;
    }
    public void ApplyChange(FloatVar amount)
    {
        Value += amount.Value;
    }
}
```

StringVar.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New StringVar", menuName = "Variables/StringVar")]
public class StringVar : BaseVarDef<string>
{
    public void SetValue(StringVar value)
    {
        Value = value.Value;
    }
    public void ApplyChange(string amount)
    {
        Value += amount;
    }
    public void ApplyChange(StringVar amount)
    {
        Value += amount.Value;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to refactor the: SetValue and the 2 overloaded ApplyChange methods into BaseVarDef.cs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think you can define all Apply and Set in Base class

```
public abstract class BaseVarDef<T>
{
    public string DeveloperDescription = "";

    public T Value;

    public void SetValue(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public void SetValue(BaseVarDef<T> value)
    {
        Value = value.Value;
    }
    public void ApplyChange(T amount)
    {
        AddValue(amount);
    }
    public void ApplyChange(BaseVarDef<T> amount)
    {
        AddValue(amount.Value);
    }

    protected abstract void AddValue(T val);
}

public class FloatVar : BaseVarDef<float>
{
    protected override void AddValue(float val)
    {
        Value += val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for this problem, specifically because I would say you SHOULD keep the child classes separate. The way AddValue works for floats and strings is very different, so declaring that operation as abstract and making child classes deal with it makes sense; this way you could later potentially implement some other class that does AddValue in a completely different manner, without using the += operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just add those methods to the original base class (and then remove the `abstract` from it), and then you just do `BaseVarDef<string>` or `BaseVarDef<float>`. No more need for the `FloatVar` or `StringVar` classes!

The tricky part here is the `+=` operator, which can't be applied to generics (at least there is no constraint I'm aware of that allows you to specify the type implements an operator).

So you could either make an abstract `Add` method that derived classes must implement as Svetlana describes, or you can use `dynamic` as shown below (and get rid of the need for derived classes altogether).

The one problem with `dynamic` is that there is no compile time checking with `dynamic` types, so it's not foolproof.  **The type `T` must overload the `+` operator or you'll get a runtime exception.** You could avoid that by wrapping the line `Value = amt + val;` in a `try/catch`, but then you may get unexpected behavior.

```
public class BaseVarDef<T>
{
    public string DeveloperDescription { get; set; } = "";

    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void SetValue(BaseVarDef<T> value)
    {
        Value = value.Value;
    }

    public void ApplyChange(T amount)
    {
        AddToValue(amount);
    }

    public void ApplyChange(BaseVarDef<T> amount)
    {
        AddToValue(amount.Value);
    }

    private void AddToValue(T amount)
    {
        dynamic amt = amount;
        dynamic val = Value;

        // Empty catch to avoid runtime exception if 'T' doesn't support the '+' operator
        try { Value = amt + val; }
        catch { }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Then just derive: FloatVar, StringVar, etc from the BaseBarDefExt class?

Comment: You don't need `FloadVar` anymore...just `BaseVarDefExt<float>`. This gets you away from having to define a derived class for each type.

Comment: Note that this is dangerous because the line `Value = amt + val;` will throw a runtime exception if the type `T` does not implement the `+` operator. You could wrap it in a `try/catch`, but Svetlana's answer handles this in a more secure way - forcing the client to implement the `AddValue` method.

Comment: I re-read your question and now understand that you wanted to combine the classes, so I've modified the answer above.